# Read DOM after jQuery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Good day! 
I tried to do drag and drop using jQuery and read DOM after it. In drop function I use append() method to append draggable to new place. But it is likely that draggable is removed from old location only after drop() method is finished rather than append() method is finished.
It may sounds strange, but here is an example.
Here is my javascript:

```
<code>

    $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('div.drag').draggable({
                        helper : 'clone',
                        opacity : 0.3
                    });

                    $('td.cell').droppable({
                        accept : function(draggable){                       
                            if($(this).find('.drag').length > 0){
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        },
                        drop : function(event, ui) {
                            $(this).append(ui.draggable);                           

                            $('#myTable').change();
                        }

                    });

                    $('#myTable').change(function() {
                        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
                        var trList = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

                        var resultString = '';
                        for (var i=0; i < trList.length; i++)
                        {
                            var tdList = trList[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                            for (var j=0; j < tdList.length; j++)
                            {
                                if(tdList[j].getElementsByTagName('div').length > 0){
                                    resultString+='row' + i + ' column ' + j + ';';
                                }                           
                            }

                        }

                        $('#result').text(resultString);
                    });
                });

<code>
```

Here is my html snippet:

`<code>


<div class="drag">drag me</div>
    <table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell">&nbsp;</td>                
        </tr>
    </table>


    <div id="result"></div>

<code>`

So, when I drag there is not new position only in the result div, but previous position is also present!

How can I avoid it?